# How to mount Razor IMU on Clearpath Husky Robot

Tags: ros, clearpath, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I hope you can help me with my Razor IMU configuration (SEN-10736).
I've followed the [razor_imu_9dof](http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof) tutorial in order to make the board work under ROS Indigo and everything works great!

I'm just getting confused about the IMU orientation on my Clearpath Husky robot: should I mount the board by aligning the x-axis (the axis which points towards the short edge with the connector holes) towards the front bumper of my robot?
Or should I use the frame orientation specified on the sensor board?

The side with the electronics component should point up or down?

By looking at the visual tool under ROS, I think I should place the IMU with the short edge pointing towards the front bumper, but what about the component side? Should it face up or down?

- The roll values should be positive
  when moving on the right side or on
  the left side?
- And the pitch values    should be
  positive when moving up or    down?

Thank you!

EDIT:

[image: image description]

EDIT2:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256370/how-to-mount-razor-imu-on-clearpath-husky-robot/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-08-08**:
did you find razor imu to work better than the um7 that comes with the husky?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2018-08-08**:
I have a very old husky version and it doesn't include any imu sensor so I can't help you, sorry

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2018-08-08**:
The razor surely worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the [documentation for the razor imu](http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof), section "Coordinate Frames" (You have to select indigo first):

> The definition of the coordinate frame used by the Razor_AHRS firmware differs from what is printed on the board and also from the ROS coordinate frame. You will be exposed to these differences when testing the Razor AHRS and ROS topic output in the testing section below.

> The Razor_AHRS firmware uses:

> X axis pointing forward (towards the short edge with the connector holes)

> Y axis pointing to the right

> Z axis pointing down

> Ignore the labelling on the board and use this coordinate frame when mounting the Razor.

So to answer your question, you are correct:

- Ignore the axis labels
- Components up
- Roll positive clockwise
- Pitch positive on front down

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2017-03-08**:
Thank you for your answer! I edited my first post in order to add a picture. The Z-axis should point UP since the Z-axis of the robot points up, is it correct?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-03-08**:
This is correct.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2017-03-08**:
Thank you for your support!